Network Setup Service Randomly restarts (NetSetupSvc)
I have been dealing with this issue for months now and have run out of ideas to solve it. Lots of posts around this topic in various forums and no real solution from Microsoft. Has anybody here seen this issue and has a solution been published? Any other ideas to troubleshoot this?
Environment is
Windows Server 2022 all updates installed
Network Card  Firmware / Driver are up to date
No AV Installed
Setting the service to automatic is not an option and it will go to manual automatically after few mins.
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          3/2/2024 8:42:34 AM
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      x.y.z.local
Description:
The Network Setup Service service entered the running state.
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          3/2/2024 8:43:03 AM
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      x.y.z.local
Description:
The Network Setup Service service entered the stopped state.
Thank you

This is not an issue due to service is configured for "Trigger Start", and designed to function in precisely this manner.
You may be looking for what is initiating the usage of the service. One test may be to stop and disable the service, then check the event logs to see if there are any warnings or errors due to the unavailability of the service.
